# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (Angular 8)(header)

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-httpclient

I am getting this error when i try to log out.

```
`core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at http.js:165
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.lazyInit (http.js:153)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:274)
    at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:376)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2342)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeTo.js:20
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)`
```

But when I send the HTTP request from the postman, the code works. [I successfully logged out when I used the postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frjqc.png)

**My Auth Service**

```
`logout(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': this.token }); //this.token is the value of token(eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpX...)
  let options = { headers: headers };
    localStorage.clear()
    this.token=null;
    return this.http.post<response>('http://localhost:3000/users/logout',null,options).pipe(map(res=>{
      console.log(res)
       return res
    }))}
```

`
Here is the code where i Subscribe to this http request:

```
 onLogout(){

    this.authService.logout(this.dataService.storingToken).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      if(res.status===true){
      this.router.navigate(["/login"])

 }else{
        console.log("some error has occurred")
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Not sure your problem comes from here where are you calling length?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions? Did you fix your issue?

Answer (score 5):

That error is not from your code (but it's caused by it).

The error references http.js line 165 of Angular HttpClient module, which is the following snippet (in Angular 8 at least):

```
        this.lazyInit = (/**
         * @return {?}
         */
        () => {
            this.headers = new Map();
            Object.keys(headers).forEach((/**
             * @param {?} name
             * @return {?}
             */
            name => {
                /** @type {?} */
                let values = headers[name];
                /** @type {?} */
                const key = name.toLowerCase();
                if (typeof values === 'string') {
                    values = [values];
                }
                if (values.length > 0) { // <=== THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS ===
                    this.headers.set(key, values);
                    this.maybeSetNormalizedName(name, key);
                }
            }));
        });
```

Most likely the values of the headers are not being set. I would recommend first removing the headers altogether, and see if the error goes away. If it does go away, add them back one at a time.

See if the token is actually being set (that it's not undefined). You can add a console.log(this.token) at the begining of the logout() method.

Also you don't need to explicitely set the Content-Type most of the time, as Angular can take care of that automatically in most cases. You can remove that, and see if it makes any difference.

The fact that you are being logged out successfully probably means that you are passing the headers properly (explicitely) in Postman, but not passing them propertly in Angular (as indicated by the error). Also, your back-end may just not be doing the validation propertly. So the fact that you can logout with Postman doesn't relate to this issue in a significant way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the headers are not being set. You can try setting the headers in this way
Create a property `headers: any = ''` in your class

`this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set("Authorization",this.token)`

And later use them in your request